# MS Access: Typing in a multiselect combobox for searching

Tags: ms-access, combobox, multi-select

My workplace is migrating our data over to Microsoft Access and we're developing a form to submit new data. We're having one issue though and that's with a multiselect combobox. We're using this one specifically to select persons of interest and, since there's going to be a lot of people in our database, would like to be able to "search" for specific ones. E.g I have to scroll between 300 people and I have a "Jane Doe" as well as a "Steven  Harper" in mind to select, I would like to type their names and have Access jump to the option.

With a regular combobox, I can type in the box and it narrows down the options that fit what I've typed. However, with a multiselect combobox I can't for some reason. I've compared the settings for both a normal and multiselect combobox and they're the same, I haven't added any code as I don't know if that would be helpful (also a little unfamiliar with VBA and trying to learn it right now). Any insight would be great. I can't provide pictures at the immediate moment but I can do so once I get back into work.

Comment: AFAIK, a combobox can only be multi-select when it is bound to a field that is setup in table to accept multi-values. I do not recommend multi-value field.

Comment: And multi-select combobox doesn't allow typing into the box, only checking list items.

Comment: Would there be no way to code the ability to type in? Is it locked to no typing?

Comment: That is the nature of multi-select combobox. It is for use with a multi-value field.